# crystal report problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Table which Contains items and its prices and those prices some in Dollars and the rest in pounds and the items are divided into sections

and I want to use a modified Sum function in the Crystal Report so as to show at the end of each group the total in pounds

like that in C#

```
int price=0;
foreach (item it in items)
{ 
    if (it.curr=="$")
 { price+=it.price*DollarPrice }
else
price+=it.price;
    }
return price;
```

That's exactly what i want to do in crystal reports but i dont have any clue how to do so

So if you have any Idea please help me,

Regards,

Baher.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do that using the report's [formula editor](http://www.willydev.net/InsiteCreation/v1.0/descargas/prev/crystalreports_capitulo07_usandoeditorformulas.pdf).

Comment: I did Sum all the records by the formula editor but i could not multiply the price of a specific record by the dollar's price

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the next recomendation assumes you have a column in your datatable called Curr which stores the kind of currency. You have to make a new formula in the Formula Field of your CR and put something like this:

```
if {DataTableItem.curr} = '$' then
{DataTableItem.Price}*YourDollarPriceValue
else
{DataTableItem.Price}*YourPoundPriceValue;
```

And you put this Formula in your Details Section.